# unity5のキャラクタの移動時の描画のブレに関しての質問です

Tags: unity3d

こんにちは。
unity5.2を使っていてスプライトで２Ｄゲームを作ろうとしたときに、単純な移動がたまに（３秒くらいおきにガクガクっとブレる）不安定なときがあります。
それはキャラクタが画面に大きいほど顕著に現れ、キャラクタにカメラを親子付けするとキャラクタはブレなくなるのですが背景がぶれます。

```
void Update() {
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * movex * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

上のようなシンプルなコードでもぶれがありますが、アクションゲームを作っている人は移動時に補完か何かの対策を入れて滑らかに動くようにしているのでしょうか？
unityのサンプルに入っていた２Ｄのアクションも単純な移動時にブレがあるように思います。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
フレームレートをあげてみましたが、多少の軽減はするもののやはりブレが気になるので研究します。

Answer (score 1):

Updateはそもそも一定周期を保証してないので、その中で移動計算させた場合に一定速度で移動しないこともあります。（故に Time.deltaTimeで計算する必要がある）

ただ、フレームレートが低い場合に確かにブレが目立つことがあります。これはフレームレート（更新周期）を上げることで解決・軽減することができます。

スクリプト内に Application.targetFrameRate = 60; と記述するか、下記のドキュメントを参考に Quality Settings 設定を確認してみてください。

http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html